# Stream intrinsic degrades performance

Tags: assembly, vectorization, sse, intrinsics, avx

I'm playing around with the _mm_stream_ps intrinsic and I'm having some trouble with understanding its performance.

Here is a code snippet that I'm working with... 
Stream version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#include <immintrin.h>

#define NUM_ELEMENTS 10000000L

static void copy_temporal(float* restrict x, float* restrict y)
{
   for(uint64_t i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS/2; ++i){
      _mm_store_ps(y,_mm_load_ps(x));
      _mm_store_ps(y+4,_mm_load_ps(x+4));
      x+=8;
      y+=8;
   }
}
static void copy_nontemporal(float* restrict x, float* restrict y)
{
   for(uint64_t i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS/2; ++i){
      _mm_stream_ps(y,_mm_load_ps(x));
      _mm_stream_ps(y+4,_mm_load_ps(x+4));
      x+=8;
      y+=8;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   uint64_t sizeX = sizeof(float) * 4 * NUM_ELEMENTS;
   float *x = (float*) _mm_malloc(sizeX,32);
   float *y = (float*) _mm_malloc(sizeX,32);

   //initialization
   for(uint64_t i = 0 ; i < 4 * NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
      x[i] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      y[i] = 0;
   }

   printf("%g MB allocated\n",(2 * sizeX)/1024.0/1024.0); 

   double start = omp_get_wtime();
   copy_nontemporal(x, y);
   double time = omp_get_wtime() - start;
   printf("Bandwidth (non-temporal): %g GB/s\n",((3 * sizeX)/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0)/time);

   start = omp_get_wtime();
   copy_temporal(x, y);
   time = omp_get_wtime() - start;
   printf("Bandwidth: %g GB/s\n",((3 * sizeX)/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0)/time);

   _mm_free(x);
   _mm_free(y);

   return 0;
}
```

Performance results:

```
2.3 GHz Core i7 (I7-3615QM) (Laptop):
    305.176 MB allocated
    Bandwidth (non-temporal): 24.2242 GB/s
    Bandwidth: 21.4136 GB/s

Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz (cluster (exclusive job)):
    305.176 MB allocated
    Bandwidth (non-temporal): 8.33133 GB/s
    Bandwidth: 8.20684 GB/s
```

What really puzzles me is that I see better performance -- on the Xeon CPU (not on my laptop) -- if I use the non-aligned loads and stores (i.e. storeu_ps/ loadu_ps):

```
305.176 MB allocated
Bandwidth (non-temporal): 8.30105 GB/s
Bandwidth: 12.7056 GB/s
```

I would expect the stream-version to be faster than the non-stream version -- due to the redundant loads of y. However, measurements show that the stream-version is actually two times slower than the non-stream version.

Do you have any explanation for this?

Compiler used: Intel 14.0.1;
Compiler flags: -O3 -restrict -xAVX;
CPU used: Intel Xeon E5-2650;

Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to unroll the loops.  Loop unrolling is only helpful in dependency chains and there is no dependency chain.  The CPU can take care of this for you.  I have a question though.  What is the factor of 3 in your bandwidth calculation?

Comment: Two reads + one write. Even though the non-temporal version does only do one read I kept the factor of three to make a comparison simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ScottD pointed out, the answer to the question lies in the generated assembly code.
Apparently the Intel compiler is smart enough to detect the access pattern and automatically generates non-temporal loads even for the temporal version.

Here is a the compiler-generated assembly code for the temporal version:

```
..___tag_value___Z13copy_temporalPfS_.35:                       #
        xor       edx, edx                                      #22.4
        xor       eax, eax                                      #
..B2.2:                         # Preds ..B2.2 ..B2.1
        vmovups   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi]                   #23.34
        inc       rdx                                           #22.4
        vmovntps  XMMWORD PTR [rax+rsi], xmm0                   #23.20
        vmovups   xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [16+rax+rdi]                #24.36
        vmovntps  XMMWORD PTR [16+rax+rsi], xmm1                #24.20
        vmovups   xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [32+rax+rdi]                #23.34
        vmovntps  XMMWORD PTR [32+rax+rsi], xmm2                #23.20
        vmovups   xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [48+rax+rdi]                #24.36
        vmovntps  XMMWORD PTR [48+rax+rsi], xmm3                #24.20
        add       rax, 64                                       #22.4
        cmp       rdx, 5000000                                  #22.4
        jb        ..B2.2        # Prob 99%                      #22.4
```

The question which still remains is the following:

Why does the non-aligned, temporal version perform better than the non-temporal version for the CPU E5-2650 (see above). I've already looked at the generated assembly code and the compiler really generates vmovups instructions (due to the non existing alignment).

Comment: It's disappointed if ICC does something different then what you tell it.  I would prefer if it implements the intrinsic they way you intended them.

Answer (score 3):

The stream variation creates pipelined burst writes directly to DRAM. The speed should roughly match the speed of your DRAM. The standard store writes to cache (but if the data is not already in the cache, it reads it into cache first). If the data is already in cache, the standard store runs at the speed of cache writes. In general, writes with size much larger than the last level cache size are much faster using the stream method. Small writes are often faster using standard stores. Try running the test using a buffer size of a couple of GB. The stream method should be faster.

Here is a benchmark to demonstrate:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  queryPerformanceCounter - similar to QueryPerformanceCounter, but returns
//                            count directly.

uint64_t queryPerformanceCounter (void)
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER int64;
    QueryPerformanceCounter (&int64);
    return int64.QuadPart;
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// queryPerformanceFrequency - same as QueryPerformanceFrequency, but returns  count direcly.

uint64_t queryPerformanceFrequency (void)
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER int64;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency (&int64);
    return int64.QuadPart;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void testNontemporal (float *x, float *y, uint64_t numberOfVectors)
    {
    uint64_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfVectors / 2; ++i)
        {
        _mm_stream_ps(y,_mm_load_ps(x));
        _mm_stream_ps(y+4,_mm_load_ps(x+4));
        y+=8; x+=8;
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void testTemporal (float *x, float *y, uint64_t numberOfVectors)
    {
    uint64_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfVectors / 2; ++i)
        {
        _mm_store_ps(y,_mm_load_ps(x));
        _mm_store_ps(y+4,_mm_load_ps(x+4));
        y+=8; x+=8;
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void runtests (int nonTemporal)
    {
    uint64_t startCount, elapsed, index;
    float *x, *y;
    uint64_t numberOfBytes = 400 * 0x100000ull;
    uint64_t numberOfFloats = numberOfBytes / sizeof *x;
    uint64_t numberOfVectors = numberOfFloats / 4;
    double gbPerSecond;

    x = _mm_malloc (numberOfBytes, 32);
    y = _mm_malloc (numberOfBytes, 32);
    if (x == NULL || y == NULL) exit (1);

    // put valid floating point data into the source buffer
    // to avoid performance penalty
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfFloats; index++)
        x [index] = (float) index, y [index] = 0;

    startCount = queryPerformanceCounter ();
    if (nonTemporal)
        testNontemporal (x, y, numberOfVectors);
    else
        testTemporal (x, y, numberOfVectors);
    elapsed = queryPerformanceCounter () - startCount;
    gbPerSecond = (double) numberOfBytes / 0x40000000 * queryPerformanceFrequency () / elapsed;
    printf ("%.2f GB/s\n", gbPerSecond);
    _mm_free (x);
    _mm_free (y);
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void)
    {
    // raise our priority to increase measurement accuracy
    SetPriorityClass (GetCurrentProcess (), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);

    printf ("using temporal stores\n");
    runtests (0);
    printf ("using non-temporal stores\n");
    runtests (1);
    return 0;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output from Intel Core i7-2600K:

```
using temporal stores
5.57 GB/s
using non-temporal stores
8.35 GB/s
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm already using buffers of size 400MB (i.e. much lager than any cache in my system). Moreover, I've instrumented the code in order to read some hardware counters and the results are conclusive (i.e. using stream_ps results in less l2 write misses). However, I still can't explain the big performance delta between these two versions.

Comment: I am going to add an example benchmark that tries to show the non-temporal (streaming) advantage for large buffers. It is a bit quick and dirty, but I think correct. Non-portable (Windows) timing functions are used.

Comment: I've updated my original post but I cannot reproduce your results (even if I port your code to Linux, the results remain the same). Do you have any idea why this is the case? Moreover, do you have an explanation for why the non-aligned version is faster? This could actually point to the real problem, because stream does expect alignment.

Comment: @ScottD, I ran your tests in MSVC.  Running them a few times and the results swap back an forth.  Both methods have the same speed within the uncertainty.

Comment: @Z, are you using an optimized release build or debug build? I get what you describe when running the debug build. But a release build (or command line cl -Ox stream.c) works as expected.

Comment: @ScottD, btw, you may be interested in this http://agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip. If you look at Fog's memcpy assembly code you see who uses store_ps for values less than have the cache and stream_ps over half the cache (well he uses the AVX versions if it exsits) and has cases for SSE and SSE3 as well.

Comment: @Z, with the example code from user1829358 I can get the same result flip flop as you see. I am pretty sure this is due to processor core power states, better known as boost or turbo boost. Ideally, a single thread on a lightly loaded system will will get immediately boosted to the max processor frequency. But some things can interfere with boost. One short duration thread execution. Apparently it can take many ms before boost is activated. Increasing

Comment: [ignore previous] @Z, with the example code from user1829358 I can get the same result flip flop as you see. I am pretty sure this is due to processor core power states, better known as boost or turbo boost. Ideally, a single thread on a lightly loaded system will will get immediately boosted to the maximum processor frequency. But some things can interfere with boost. One is short duration thread execution. Apparently it can take many ms before boost is activated. Doubling the test buffer size eliminated the flip flop on my system. (more)

Comment: (continued) Other things that can interfere with boost: With many AMD processors, Windows 7, the Windows 7 default power plan (Balanced) completely blocks boost. You must change it to 'High Performance' for boost to ever work. With recent Intel based HP ProLiant servers, boost may not work using default BIOS settings. You must change the power management to 'OS Control' in BIOS. Also, make sure the test is running long enough for omp_get_wtime() to give accurate results. On my Win7+mingw 4.8.2 system, this function updates only once per 16 ms.

Comment: @ScottD: I cannot reproduce your results using my test code. Even if I  double the buffer size the my results remain the same. Please not that I'm showing results for two different systems. I'm especially interested in an explanation for the faster unaligned loads. Have you tried using my code with unaligned loads? (My compiler flags are shown above.)

Comment: Additional note: I've implemented a different timing method based on rdtsc and the results still do not change.

Comment: @user1829358: this is a long shot... but have you checked your code generation? I don't have the Intel compiler but I know it is pretty clever. Is it possible the compiler recognizes sequential writes to a large buffer and substitutes non-temporal stores for the temporal stores in your code? That would make the two versions the same. Another option is to see if gcc produces the same result.

Comment: @user1829358: Using gcc.godbolt.org to show Intel compiler code generation makes it look like the Intel compiler really is using non-temporal writes for both loops. That would explain why the expected performance delta between the two loops is not present.

Comment: @ScottD: this is a great website! Thanks for pointing this out, it solves the original question. Now I'm only left with an answer to the  question why unaligned loads/stores perform better on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, non-temporal stores drop the target cacheline from all caches. If the line is touched again before it would have been dropped naturally, you've lost pretty hard.

Comment: I was going to say that it depends on the size of the buffers in question, but your comment to ScottD indicates that they are very large. At this point I'm not sure what's going on. You might try various things like commenting out the `#pragma`s, compiling without `-xAVX`, etc, looking for a change in the ratio of performance between regular and non-temporal stores.